Sitecore Powershell script raises the memory consumption and does not release memory
I'm running the following script for 36K items and the memory starts raising and eventually crashes CM server.
 $refassets = @()
        $items = @()
        $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Home/Products/"   -Recurse 


        $assetTemplateID = "{C2214D4C-883E-4B9C-B97A-C9CC00A1764E}"
        # Loop through each item
        foreach ($item in $items) {           
            # Get related items using source template
            $sourceRefs = Get-ItemReference  -Item $item  | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -eq $assetTemplateID }
        
                        foreach ($ref in $sourceRefs) {

                           $refAsset = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
                                        L1 = $startingPath
                                        ProductName   = $item.Name
                                        ProductPath = $item.Paths.FullPath 
                                        ProductEntityID = $item.Fields["{B51F49BC-3628-4414-AB84-57A85DD4C243}"]
                                        ProductGUID = $item.ID
                                        ProductLevel = $item.Fields["productLevel"]
                                        AssetID = $ref.Fields["AssetID"]
                                        AssetName = $ref.Name
                                        AssetFullPath = $ref.Paths.FullPath
                                        AssetGUID = $ref.ID
                                        ResourceType = $resourceType
                                        Unpublished =  $ref.Fields["__Never publish"].Value

                                    }
                        
                        $refassets.Add($refAsset)
            } 
        }   
        "Completed Processing"
         $refassets | Show-ListView

        $refassets.Dispose()
        $items.Dispose()
        Remove-Variable Name * 
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        
    

We have tried

Remove-Variable , Dispose() and [System.GC]::Collect()
Set the Powershell ISE session to Dispose session after script execution
Waited for an hour to see if memory releases.

Nothing helped so far.

$refassets.Add is just not possible if $refassets = @() so you should actually paste the real code you have

Use the PowerShell pipeline as it is meant to be used: Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Home/Products/" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -eq $assetTemplateID } | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{ ... } | Show-ListView were the  Show-ListView command will probaly pile up everything in memory to display it and therefore better use the native command Format-List.

I’ve not used the SiteCore cmdlets, so take this with a pick of salt, but it looks like you’re accessing the Value property of a field in Unpublished =  $ref.Fields["__Never publish"].Value but for other properties like AssetID you’re storing a reference to the Field object (e.g. AssetID = $ref.Fields["AssetID"]). I don’t know what the overhead of that would be, but it’s potentially keeping each item’s entire object graph alive. If you store  the scalar Value property value instead it’ll allow the GC to clean up unreferenced objects…
